# Нечитаемые символы в cout

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ascii

Вот весь код, подскажите пожалуйста на каком этапе ломается читаемость и как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int Comp1(const void* a, const void* b);

int Comp2(const void* a, const void* b);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(0));
    char mass1[31];
    char mass2[51];

    int temp = 0;
    int new_size1 = 0;
    int new_size2 = 0;

    int *nums = new int [new_size1];
    char *symbs = new char [new_size2+1];

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)            //рандомим первый массив
    {
        mass1[i] = rand() % 127;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)            //рандомим второй массив
    {
        mass2[i] = rand() % 127;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)            //считаем сколько цифр и букв в первом
    {
        if (isdigit (mass1[i])) {
            new_size1++;
        } else if (isalpha (mass1[i])) {
            new_size2++;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)            //считаем сколько цифр и букв во втором
    {
        if (isdigit (mass2[i])) {
            new_size1++;
        } else if (isalpha (mass2[i])) {
            new_size2++;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)            //цифри из первого массива к цифрам
    {
        if (isdigit (mass1[i])) {
            nums[temp] = mass1[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)            //цифри из второго массива к цифрам
    {
        if (isdigit (mass2[i])) {
            nums[temp] = mass2[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Всего цифр должно быть: " << new_size1 << endl;
    temp = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)            //буквы из первого массива к буквам
    {
        if (isalpha (mass1[i])) {
            symbs[temp] = mass1[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)            //буквы из второго массива к буквам
    {
        if (isalpha (mass2[i])) {
            symbs[temp] = mass2[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Всего букв должно быть: " << new_size2 << endl << endl;
    temp = 0;

    cout << "Вот цифры из массивов: ";
    for (int i=0; i<new_size1; i++)
    {
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Вот цифры по возрастанию: ";
    qsort(nums, new_size1, sizeof(int), Comp2);
    for (int i=0; i<new_size1; i++)
    {
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Вот буквы из массивов: ";
    for (int i=0; i<new_size2; i++)
    {
        cout << symbs[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<new_size2; i++)
    {
        symbs[i] = (char)tolower(symbs[i]);
    }

    qsort(symbs, strlen(symbs), sizeof(*symbs), Comp1);
    cout << "А теперь по алфавиту: ";
    for (int i=0; i<new_size2; i++)
    {
        cout << symbs[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;


    return 0;
}

int Comp1(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(char*)a-*(char*)b;
}

int Comp2(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(int*)a-*(int*)b;
}
```

[image: Пример ошибки]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Первые же строки уже ошибочны

```
int new_size1 = 0;
int new_size2 = 0;    
int *nums = new int [new_size1];
char *symbs = new char [new_size2+1];
создаете массивы с размером ноль...
```